# como agregar el atributo required a un input a traves de un button

Tags: javascript, funciones, input, parametros, required

Hola quiero agregar un required a un input al ya le agregue unas clases y la remuevo quisiera agregar el parametro como tal.

```
    const addClassBtn = document.getElementById('changeColor')
      const handleColor = () => {
        addClassBtn.classList.add('btype')
        addClassBtn.classList.add('caution')
        addClassBtn.addEventListener()
      }
      const removeClassBtn = document.getElementById('changeColor')
      const noClass = () => {
        removeClassBtn.classList.remove('btype')
        removeClassBtn.classList.remove('caution')
      }
```

agrego imagen de cuando se agregan las clases cuando se cargan con el boton CARGAR DATOS PREDETERMINADOS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y finalmente la imagen donde se remueven las clases al dar clic en el boton INGRESAR CUOTAS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes usar control.required=true, o bien control.setAtributte('required',true);

Comment: Mil Gracias Heyner Martinez